# How do I make my game end when my character hits the boundaries?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a game with an SKSprite node which is my character "Knight" and I'm trying to make it so if he hits any boundary of the screen, the game ends. I already have it so if he touches the ground the game ends but I want the game to end if he touches any of the boundaries, not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help!

```
struct PhysicsCatagory {
static let Knight : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
static let border : UInt32 = 0x1 << 5
}

var Knight = SKSpritenode()

override functions didMove(to view: SKView) {
Knight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CJKnightNew")
    Knight.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 120)
    Knight.position = CGPoint(x: -10, y: 200)
    Knight.zPosition = 7

    Knight.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Knight.frame.height / 2)
    Knight.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Knight
    Knight.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.land
    Knight.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.land | PhysicsCatagory.Score | PhysicsCatagory.Ground
    Knight.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Knight.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    Knight.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
border.friction = 0
self.physicsBody = border
}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
let firstBody = contact.bodyA
let secondBody = contact.bodyB

if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Knight && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.border || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.border && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Knight {

        died = true
    }
}
```

I have it so if died = true it ends the game, but for some reason this isn't working? When the knight hits the boundary it should make the game end. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How is "died" variable connected to game logic ?

Comment: check your contactTestBitMask, you are missing PhysicsCatagory.border there